# Проблема с библиотекой Google Services 4.3.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

Обновил библиотеку с

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

до

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Возникла проблема при синхронизации. В чем может быть причина?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может конфликтует с чем-то, чисто как вариант можно оставить версию пониже

Comment: Таки на en-SO о том же спрашивают и ответов нема. Наверное таки лучше всего пока что откатиться до предыдущей версии. С либами гугла это норма. После апдейта часто всё ломается. Вряд ли поможет, но попробуйте добавить в конец `build.gradle (module app)` `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`